# "Compensation" filter in Jobs tab is restricted to 6 digits

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, internationalization

While exploring the [Jobs tab](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs), I noticed that the "Compensation" filter is restricted to 6 digits. I am from India where the currency is in [INR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rupee), and with the six digit restriction, the maximum salary which I could pass over there is 999,999 INR which is less than 14k US Dollars.

[image: Compensation Filter - SO Jobs]

The average salary of a software engineer with a few years of experience is in 7 digits over here. I know people with around 15 years of experience earning INR 6,000,000+.

The restriction of compensation filter to 999,999 doesn't provides good job search experience to people who are looking for high paying jobs. For example, person earning INR 6,000,000 won't be interested in looking at a job offering INR 1,200,000.

I think we should remove the restriction of maximum digits from this search filter. Or, at least we should extend it for currencies like INR where people earn in 7 or more digits.

Comment: I enjoy this example of looking behind the horizon.

Comment: Can the limit be adjusted along with the currency? Or is that bad UX?

Comment: Seems like a development oversight. Someone might have thought "no developer job on our platform will pay a million (dollars or euros) a year" without thinking of currencies that feature much larger denominations.

Comment: These kind of things always makes me a little sad :(, because it feels like people aren't realizing/caring they are developing international software. To me the whole salary thing feels 'American'.

Comment: The meaning of "," and "." should also changed based on the currency

Comment: @Mixxiphoid yeah, it's as if Jobs is developed for the USA market, and internationalisation is an afterthought.

Comment: "with a few years of experience" ... There are many roles for newly graduated  developers (freshers), which are in 7 digits (and more than 50% of the students in the decent colleges get those). This restriction is certainly an issue.

Comment: @BhargavRao : That's correct, and that's why I used the term *"average"* salary. Because most of the software engineers in India work in service based companies where it takes them 5-6 years to reach to that level. Coming back to our point, as you said, this restriction is certainly an issue.

Comment: Is there a version of [falsehoods programmers believe about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) for currency?

Comment: Many that write specs deserve blame. And some that are blamed deserve specs. Can you give it to them? Then do not be too eager to deal out blame in judgement.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Found one: https://gist.github.com/rgs/6509585

Comment: @Stijn not even that, in the US graduates with a graduate degree in machine learning can get 7 figure jobs according to some of the hype I've seen.

Comment: @DanNeely maybe with stock and other options, not base salary.

Comment: I'm sure that Dr Evil would want to work for more than US$14K in India.

Comment: Things like this gripe me because there is no reason why you should even restrict it. So what if some developer enters "12345678910", they'll just get no job matches. And if someone accidentally enters an extra 0 in "100000" they'll figure it out, no need to prevent it.

Comment: In Vietnam any job with any training requirements would make millions... in a month, if not week or day. And in Zimbabwe not that long ago being called a millionaire would have been an insult :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks for pointing that out - I removed the maxlength attribute from the minimum annual salary input, so it shouldn't be a problem going forward!